# Explanation on how this makefile works?

Tags: c, makefile, autotools

I found a makefile [here](http://markuskimius.wikidot.com/programming%3atut%3aautotools:2) while reading about Auto-Tools.

I never used a makefile like this, I tried this myself.
The contents of makefile I wrote are:

```
all: HelloWorld

clean:
    rm -f HelloWorld *.o
```

The folder containing the makefile contains just one more file `HelloWorld.c`.

Running `make` was successful with following output:

```
$> make
cc     HelloWorld.c   -o HelloWorld
```

Now I tried experimenting, and in the makefile I renamed the target for `all` to `HelloWorl`. This time `make` failed with following error:

```
$> make
make: *** No rule to make target `HelloWorl', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

Please explain this behaviour of `make` automatically searching and compiling the source.

My understanding is that it is making the source name from the target name by appending `.c` and compiles it using the default `cc` compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding is mostly correct; this is one of the [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules). However, `make` actually compiles the file using the compiler in make's [`CC` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html).